# How to create excel file if it does not exist

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to add a tab to existing excel files. If the file does not exist I would like to create one. But with my current program I am having an error.

Here is the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Here is my code:

```
    book = load_workbook(out_path)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    df.to_excel(writer,"Autocoded",index = False)
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
```

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

```
    if os.path.isfile(out_path):
        book = load_workbook(out_path)
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(out_path, engine='openpyxl')
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
        df.to_excel(writer,"Autocoded",index = False)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
    else:
        df.to_excel(out_path)
```